# How can I add radio button and VBO(view bulk operation) module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want to make a VBO(*view bulk operation module*) in drupal, with radio buttons instead of a checkbox for each field of my view. 
Is it any way to configure VBO for this purpose? Or should I use another module?
My problem is to make a list of a node type and for each of them set a status and finally submit status for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to this issue: http://drupal.org/node/724686. Functionality for D7 is done, D6 to follow.